# What are the advantages of having a definition of pure virtual method In C++?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Although pure virtual methods typically have no implementation in the class that declares them, pure virtual methods in some languages (e.g. C++ and Python) are permitted to contain an implementation in their declaring class. What are the benefits of doing so, since C++ allows this behavior?

```
class Abstract
{
    public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

void Abstract::show() { print("Default Implementation"); }

class Derived : public Abstract
{
    public:
    void show() override { print("Overridden Implementation"); }
};
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not a discussion forum*. Questions like these, trying to debate pros and cons and design decisions, are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: As an aside, Python doesn't actually have this concept. The closest you can get is methods that explicitly raise a particular sort of exception to indicate the "pure" virtual status (and *everything* is "virtual", and actually even more flexible than the C++ concept).